# What is the difference between output-channel and reply-channel in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I noticed that a lot of SI components has both: `reply-channel` and `output-channel`. For example payload enricher: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.14.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher

From docs:

**output-channel** -

> Identifies the Message channel where a Message will be sent after it
>   is being processed by this endpoint.Optional.

**reply-channel** -

> Channel where a reply Message is expected. This is optional; typically
>   the auto-generated temporary reply channel is sufficient. Optional.

Could you clarify the difference ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `request-channel` and `reply-channel` are equivalent for `input-channel` and `output-channel` when talk about *gateway*-like components. When the component in general as a *service-activator* (like the mentioned `ericher`), the `input-channel` is where is component expects an input message for processing; the `output-channel`, where this component will send an output message. Its logic is about *requesting* some data externally, so its `request-channel` is where this component is going to request. The `reply-channel` where to expect reply from sub-flow.

In many other *outbound gateways* you should treat `request-channel` == `input-channel` and `reply-channel` == `output-channel`.

Comment: So for enricher the "flow" is input-channel --> request-channel  --> reply-channel ---> output-channel ?

Comment: Something like that. You can omit `reply-channel`, since an internal gateway will use a `replyChannel` header with a `TemporaryReplyChannel` anyway. You also ca avoid `output-channel` if you are interest in the immediate reply into the caller, like a `@MessagingGateway`.

Comment: Could you provide example when I need to configure these channels ?

Comment: In most cases you indeed need an `output-channel` because you may send a result into some other endpoint for further processing. Usually we don't do `reply-channel` for any *inbound* gateway (like that internal for enricher). See its description in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#gateway-default-reply-channel